# Drive on Windows 10 shows incorrect image and no name

Tags: windows-10

I have a bit on a strange issue on Windows 10. As seen in the image below, the E drive (which is a regular drive and not a Pictures library) is displaying the pictures image and not displaying the name.

If I go to This PC, it doesn't look like this. It shows up alongside the rest of my drives. I've tried to reset the image in properties but it doesn't fix. Anyone have any ideas on correcting this?

Thanks,
t

[image: Drive image incorrect]